# Traduction de « it takes two to tango »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

En anglais « *it takes two to tango* » veut dire deux choses en général.

1. Deux parties ont besoin de coopérer pour faire quelque chose donc il faut le faire ensemble.
2. (négatif) Deux parties ont fait quelque chose ensemble donc si quelque chose de mal est arrivé, c'est la faute des deux parties et pas seulement de l'une d'entre elles.

Existe-t-il une expression équivalente en français ?

Comment: « Partie » ne convient pas ici comme traduction de *party*. En français, dans ce sens, « partie » est strictement juridique (« les parties contractantes » = « *the contracting parties* »). Il n'y a pas de traduction exacte, le mot le plus naturel ici serait *personne*.

Comment: Merci pour la correction.  Au début j'ai utilisé « personne » et puis je l'ai changé car je voulais dire que les deux personnes auraient pu représenter deux groupes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ce n'est vas véritablement une expression, mais tu peux dire :

> Il faut être deux pour [quelque chose].

C'est très naturel, et sera parfaitement compris dans les deux sens que tu évoques.

En québecois, le calque « ça prend [des ressources] pour [quelque chose] » est tout à fait normal.

Answer (score 5):

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait d'expression équivalente. On trouve quelquefois l'expression « il faut être deux pour danser le tango » (en référence à [la même chanson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takes_Two_to_Tango_%28song%29) ou à la façon dont l'expression a été [reprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takes_two_to_tango_%28idiom%29)), mais elle est plus rare qu'en anglais et ne sera souvent pas reconnue comme idiomatique.

Par contre, la racine « il faut être deux pour [faire quelque chose] » est transparente et peut souvent être utilisée. Suivant les cas, on peut trouver d'autres expressions idiomatiques.

Pour exprimer qu'une tâche est plus facile lorsqu'elle est effectuée par deux personnes qui agissent en commun, on peut dire

> À deux, c'est mieux.
>   L'union fait la force.

La deuxième de ces expressions proverbiales s'applique souvent à un grand nombre de personnes, mais on peut aussi l'employer pour seulement deux.

Pour dire qu'une situation ne résulte pas seulement des actions d'une personne, on peut dire que la personne « n'en est pas arrivée là toute seule ». Ce n'est pas une expression proverbiale, on peut la retrouver sous de nombreuses variations.

> *— She's pregnant. Serves her right for having unprotected sex. — She? It takes two to tango.*
>   — Elle est enceinte. C'est de sa faute, elle n'avait qu'à pas avoir une relation non protégée. — De sa faute ? En partie, mais elle n'en est pas arrivée là toute seule.

Dans cette nuance là, on dit souvent « il faut être deux pour ... », par exemple « il faut être deux pour se battre ».

Pour souligner la nécessité ou le manque de coopération dans un couple (ou plus), on peut dire qu'« il faut faire des efforts des deux côtés » ou que « les torts sont partagés ».

Il existe plusieurs manières d'exprimer un besoin de concessions que doivent faire les deux parties dans un compromis. On peut dire, au cours d'une négociation, face à l'autre partie qui ne veut rien céder :

> C'est donnant-donnant. [plutôt familier]
>   Il faut un *[quid pro quo](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quid_pro_quo)*. [plutôt soutenu]
>   On n'a rien sans rien.
>   Il faut jouer le jeu.

Answer (score 0):

Si l'on recherche

> Il faut être deux pour danser

on trouve la *valse* et le *tango*.

Pour rester dans l'expression anglophone, on pourra choisir le tango, d'origine populaire,
mais la valse a plus de faveur du coté de l'Europe qui a connu les fêtes impériales.

Comment: Il me semble que la danse est tout à fait superfétatoire dans l'expression.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Certes, rechercher "il faut être deux pour" ramène d'autres contextes, mais pour rester dans celui de la question, cette proposition devrait s'intégrer facilement dans l'ambiance du texte à traduire. Cf. http://economic-research.bnpparibas.com/Views/DisplayPublicationPDF.aspx?type=document&IdPdf=21009

Comment: [Certes](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais?query=it+takes+two+to+tango&source=english). Je trouve toujours le tango (ou la valse) tout à fait incongru dans la plupart de ces traductions. *I mean*, « Madame la Présidente, il faut être deux pour danser le tango. », c'est un débat ou une proposition ? Mais c'est vrai que *valser* revient de temps en temps.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Curieusement, et c'est peut-être une impression non partagée, mais proposer de danser le *tango* avec une Présidente peut être ambiguë et perçu comme une envie de s'acoquiner, alors qu'une *valse* sera on ne peut plus respectueuse et d'une mondanité digne de son rang.

Answer (score 0):

" Pour danser la valse, il faut être deux "

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language Stack Exchange. You could significantly improve your answer by adding one or more sources that document this expression.